# Sums of realizations of dependent variables become independent

Tags: random-variables, independence, correlation, central-limit-theorem

I have empirically noticed and interesting phenomenon. Suppose we have two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are **dependent** but **not correlated**. For instance:

$X \sim \mathcal{N(0,1)}$

$Y = cos(X) +Z$,$~~~~$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N(0,0.5)}$

Here you can see some samples generated for these variables. I use [this](https://gist.github.com/satra/aa3d19a12b74e9ab7941) implementation of [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) as a measure for dependence:

[image]

Now consider two additional random variables $X_{sum}$ and $Y_{sum}$ generated as the summation of $n$ realizations of the original variables respectively. The thing I have noticed is that **$X_{sum}$ and $Y_{sum}$ become more and more independent as $n$ grows** (click on the image to enlarge):

[image]

I know that by the Central Limit Theorem $X_{sum}$ and $Y_{sum}$ will be approximately normal, but **why are they becoming independent? Is there a general explanation for this?**. Also, I have noticed that this phenomenon only occurs if $X$ and $Y$ are not correlated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [multidimensional CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT) implies that
$$\sqrt{n} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{n} X_{sum} - \mathbb{E} X \\ \frac{1}{n} Y_{sum} - \mathbb{E} Y \end{bmatrix}$$
is approximately bivariate normal with mean zero and covariance matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}\text{Var}(X) & \text{Cov}(X,Y) \\ \text{Cov}(X,Y) & \text{Var}(Y)\end{bmatrix}.$$
Since your $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, we have $\text{Cov}(X_{sum}/\sqrt{n}, Y_{sum}/\sqrt{n}) \approx 0$.

I am not sure how to quantify what happens when you scale up by $\sqrt{n}$ to consider $\text{Cov}(X_{sum}, Y_{sum})$; you may need a Berry-Esseen type of non-asymptotic result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That might explain the near cero correlation, but I am more interested in the increasingly lower dependence.

Comment: But now that I think about it, if two variables follow a bivariate normal with cero co-variance, they are by definition independent right?